# Unicode Supplementary Multilingual Plane (Plane 1) glyphs in xterm

Tags: locale, unicode, xterm

I'm trying to display Unicode Supplementary Multilingual Plane (Plane 1) glyphs in xterm. Those glyphs are in the U+010000..U+01FFFF range (https://unifoundry.com/pub/unifont/unifont-15.0.01/unifont_plane1-15.0.01.bmp).

The font is a merged version of unifont-15.0.01.hex and unifont_upper-15.0.01.hex converted to bdf and is loaded via my .Xresources file:

```
*locale: true
*ut8: true
xterm*font: -*-merged-*-*-*-16-*
```

Plane 0 (U+0000..U+FFFF) glyphs are working.

I think it could be a locale issue similar to this post: [Cannot display 8-bit characters in xterm in ubuntu 18.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529911/cannot-display-8-bit-characters-in-xterm-in-ubuntu-18-04).

I tried `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and `LANG=en_US` without success.

EDIT:
When `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` is set Unicode Supplementary Multilingual Plane (Plane 1) glyphs in xterm are displayed as a "weird square".
When I start xterm with en-US locale `LC_ALL=en_US LANG=en-US xterm` Plane 1 glyphs are not displayed and/or wrongly encoded.

Should I use a different locale? If so, which one and how? Additionally, would it be better to define "unifont_upper" as a fallback instead of merging it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitmap fonts use the X library interface [**`XDrawString16`**](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/drawing-text/XDrawString16.html) (see [source code](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/d54c7009fafee9d7f3d82398e8e2c4c248822ac6/util.c#L3814)), which as the name implies, are limited to 16-bit font indices.

Possibly [**`XmbDrawString`**](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man3/XmbDrawString.3.xhtml) could exceed this limit (but since the skimpy manpage gives no clues, one could only determine that by studying the source code).  It is not a simple replacement, as you might see from [this discussion](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/intro-i18n/intro-i18n.txt).

If you want to go past [***BMP***](https://unicode.org/roadmaps/bmp/), you have to use TrueType fonts.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'll have a look at XDrawString16 and fall back to True Type Fonts if I don't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have trouble with range more than xFFFF, I am guessing you printing with `echo -e "\u1234"`? There is a simple trick in this escape codes:

- \u1234 - print unicode symbol in the range 0000-ffff
- \U12345678 - print unicode symbol in the range 00000000-ffffffff

Comment: I'm not specifically using `echo -e` to display symbol, they could be copy pasted, in a text file, etc. `echo -e "\u1234"` works as intended and print `ሴ` while `echo -e \U12345678` prints a weird glyph with en_US.UTF-8 locale and prints `\u12345678` with en_US locale